# Find and Replace Define(Key,Value) in SED Linux

Tags: linux, bash, sed

Currently I'm trying to create a bash script for replacing new values I generated.

These values were stored in `constants.php`:

```
-----------constant.php : start-------------------
                      :
        define('PASS1', 'ABCD');
        define('PASS2', '1234');
                      :
-----------constant.php : end---------------------
```

After running script, *(using `sed`)* it should update the values of `PASS1` and `PASS 2` separately:

```
-----------constant.php : start-------------------
                      :
        define('PASS1', 'WXYZ');
        define('PASS2', '0987');
                      :
-----------constant.php : end---------------------
```

Is there a way I can find the KEY e.g. `'PASS1'` and replace the values after the comma?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the occurrence with `sed` so  `sed "/PASS1/s/'[^']*'/'WXYZ'/2"` matches any lines containing `PASS1` and does the following substitution `s/'[^']*'/'WXYZ'/2` which:

```
s/     # Substitute  
'      # Match a single quote
[^']*  # Match anything not a single quote 
'      # Match the closing single quote 
/      # Replace with 
'WXYZ' # The literal value
/2     # The 2 here matches the second quoted string, not the first.
```

---

```
# First key 
$ sed "/PASS1/s/'[^']*'/'WXYZ'/2" file

        define('PASS1', 'WXYZ');
        define('PASS2', '1234');

# Second key
$ sed "/PASS2/s/'[^']*'/'0978'/2" file

        define('PASS1', 'ABCD');
        define('PASS2', '0978');

# In one go
$ sed "/PASS1/s/'[^']*'/'WXYZ'/2;/PASS2/s/'[^']*'/'0978'/2" file

        define('PASS1', 'WXYZ');
        define('PASS2', '0978');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need replacement rules similar to this:

```
/'PASS1'/ s/, *'[^']*'/, 'WXYZ'/
```

Which finds a line containing the quoted PASS1 and replaces the next argument with the correct password. Writing such rules is tedious and error prone, so I prefer letting sed write them for me. So if the file `key-value.txt` contains:

```
PASS1 WXYZ
PASS2 0987
```

You can generate the replacement rules with:

```
<key-value.txt sed "s:\(.*\) \(.*\):/\1/ s/, *'[^']*'/, '\2'/:"
```

Output:

```
/'PASS1'/ s/, *'[^']*'/, 'WXYZ'/
/'PASS2'/ s/, *'[^']*'/, '0987'/
```

Pipe this into a second sed to make the actual replacement:

```
<key-value.txt sed "s:\(.*\) \(.*\):/\1/ s/, *'[^']*'/, '\2'/:" | sed -f - constants.php
```

Use the `-i` switch with the second sed to change constants.php "in-place".